# Does a semicolon DNS record serve any purpose?

Tags: dns

I'm helping my boss clean up our DNS records on Verizon and neither one of us is sure what to make of these. There are a couple records that consist solely of a semicolon. No record type, no address, no anything--it's just a semicolon.

Do these serve any purpose, or can we just remove those records?

Answer (score 1):

Semicolons are part of the bind [zone format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file).  However, there is no way to know how your management tools are interpreting these records.

Many DNS providers require placeholders to specify a `domain.com`.  I've seen `*`, `@`, and `#` used in various web-based DNS management tools.

I recommend contact your DNS provider for clarification as web-based DNS management tools differ.

Comment: From the linked document, a semicolon would seem to be a comment marker?

Comment: Semicolons are used for comments but there's no way to know how they are used in your web-based management tool.  You need to ask your provider for details.